# Adding DOM element with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append, element

I'm trying to add DOM element with using JQuery in that way:

```
 $("<label/>", {

    "class": "switch",  

       on:{

          click: function(event){

          let currentBlock =  $(this).parents('.item');

          if($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]'){
            currentBlock.toggle('inactive')
          }
          else{
            currentBlock.toggle('inactive')              
          }
      },

      append: '<input type="checkbox"><span class="slider round"></span>',

      appendTo: context

  });
```

And it work like a charm, but I can append to this block only one element.

I mean that piece of code:

```
append: '<input type="checkbox"><span class="slider round"></span>'
```

I tried to find in which way I can add a few elements, put theare Array or Object...but it does not work :(

Anyone has similar problem?

Comment: Do you wanna share your HTML too and make a [mcve]? It will be more helpful.

Comment: And what else do you want to add?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I am not sure that I can add the piece of Angular project to jsfiddle.net, but I gonna try

Comment: @Re_p1ay Sure. That will be helpful. Also, why are you mixing Angular and jQuery? That's a dangerous combination.

Comment: @charlietfl in that way I want create a div wich will have some paragrafs, inputs and spans

Here is an example of my JQ code adding div

https://jsfiddle.net/Rep1ay/tzvpf068/1/

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman with mechanics of working an Angular with JQ in that moment I haven't a problem...here a question more about JQ and not about Angular

Comment: Strongly suggest reading [thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) I agree with Paveen, not a good mix

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for a good article, do you think Angular 6 can have same problems?

Comment: And question is still about JQuery :)

Comment: Yes. Use  angular templating for what you are doing

Comment: Thank you guys, I will think about Angular templating.